# How to Join multiple (more than 4) `CV::Mat` images `Size(M, N), CV_8UC1` into one RGBA image?

Tags: c++, image, join, opencv, matrix

So we have created many, (say `100`) `Mat::zeros(Size(100, 100), CV_8UC1);` binary images (with values 0 or 255). We filled them with some data (that can overlay on different images). Now we want to join them into one savable RGBA image on which all data of each single Mat will be represented by unique RGB value and alpha == 0.5. How to do such thing with openCV 2?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately openCV doesn't support alpha channel and I don't think any of it's file I/O libs support transparency on any of the formats that handle it (such as PNG)

"Only 8-bit (or 16-bit in the case of PNG, JPEG 2000 and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function"  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite

You can create a 4 channel image format using CV_8UC4 and manipulate the alpha yourself but you won't be able to read/write it using imread/imwrite

Comment: You say openCV cant create transparent PNGs for example?=( I'm looking at [this nice document](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf) but still cant solve my problem even without A channel...(

Comment: Yes that shows you how to create a 4 channel image and mix it form separate single channel ones (or you can just do the pixel data combine yourself with pointers) but you can't save a RGBA using imwrite

Comment: BTW what is signature for BGR? I get some reazlly bad images with .jpg from CV_8UC3...(

Comment: There isn't a signature in the image format, the library simply assumes you are supplying it with BGR and it will convert anything you read int BGR